# DateTimePicker Month Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, windows-ce

I have an application I'm maintaining that uses the DateTimePicker to set a future date. Everything works fine except that the buttons to change the month overlap with the month and year text making them hard to read. (See attached picture)

I've tried changing the font size, which does change the overall calendar size, but the buttons stay in their relative positions. Is there a way to fix them without re-writing the entire DateTimePicker class as I've seen done for  other customization questions? (I'm still pretty new to C# so that seems like something outside of my current ability.)

[image: Broken Calendar]

11/9/2018 Update:
I've found that the calendar display is generated at an OS level. So the problem is not in C# Winform or .NET 3.5 but in Windows CE itself.

Comment: Hello, you can't change the control's width?

Comment: You can change the control width, but it only affects the text box part of it. The pop-up calendar is unaffected by anything except the CalendarFont setting as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the Month label from the numbers so when you change the month size the others don't need to change to.